# iPhone UIControl and Subview

Tags: iphone, uicontrol

I currently have a UIControl, which has a number of subviews (image, label).

Unfortunately when I use addTarget etc. It doesn't detect touches on the subviews.

```
  [myCustomView addTarget:self action:@selector(touchedView:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Is it possible for the UIControl to detect touches on subviews or should i be approaching it differently.

Answer (score 23):

Just note that all subviews of a UIControl which shouldn't receive touch events themselves must have userInteractionEnabled set to **NO** and not YES (which is the default).

So you must set this on all labels, images, etc.

I just ran into this and figured it out after a while :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I was looking for a solution for while but never thought that it would end this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your method call is correct.

myCustomView should be the image or label being added.

Comment: so i have to iterate over all the subviews and add target.

that also means that they also all have to be UIControl subclasses

Comment: "so i have to iterate over all the subviews and add target." That is correct. I think they have to be UIView subclasses, which are super classes of UIControl.

Answer (score 0):

```
[myCustomView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```